# Move console cursor up

Tags: python, console, ansi-escape

I tried to create a simple clock up the top-left corner of the console, updating every second:

```
def clock():
    threading.Timer(1.0, clock).start()
    print('\033[0;0H' + time.asctime(time.localtime()))
```

I've used the `colorama` package to enable ANSI escape sequences in Windows, but it seems the escape code would just move the cursor the number of pixels specified, and not to the position.

---

How can I move the cursor to the position `(0, 0)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line and column start at 1 not 0.

```
print('\033[1;1H' + time.asctime(time.localtime()))
```

or shorter

```
print('\033[H' + time.asctime(time.localtime()))
```

You might also need to save and restore position using ESC-7 and ESC-8.

See http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences-vt-100.php for a list of codes.

Barry